# How to recursively convert all JPGs into one PDF in each folder using img2pdf?

Tags: bash, pdf, conversion

I have three levels of folders like main, sub-1 and sub-2. my main folder has lot of sub-1 folders and sub-1 has lot of sub-2 folder with JPG images inside.

I copy JPG files from sub-2 to its parent sub-1 folder FROM main folder by using this command.

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'for p; do
  cp "$p" "${p%/*/*}"
done' _ {} +
```

Now I have to convert all jpgs into one pdf file inside each sub-1 folder from my MAIN folder, so there will be my all copied jpgs along with converted pdf in sub-1 (pdf name should be the folder name ex: sub-1). after convert finished I have to delete the copied jpgs only inside sub-1 folder (not original jpgs), so there will be many sub-2 folders with a single pdf file.

I am using img2pdf library to covert my images. and I tried this command below it does not do the work, I could not find any solution. Now how do I make this works?

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec bash -c 'img2pdf *.jpg -o "${PWD##*/}".pdf' {} + \
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
find . -name '*.png' -type f -exec bash -c 'name={} &&  img2pdf {} -o "${name/.png/.pdf}" ' \;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).